# Using paste command inside shell script

Tags: shell, unix, paste

I have 3 text files. I would like to read them and store them in different variables and later concatenate them using paste and print them in console.
I tried the following code but it threw an error saying

> File not found

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh
value_1=`cat file_1.txt`
value_2=`cat file_2.txt`
value_3 = paste $value_1 $value_2
echo "$value_3"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paste` expects its arguments to be the names of files, not the content of files.  With bash, ksh, or zsh, there is a way around this.  Replace:

```
paste $value_1 $value_2
```

with:

```
paste <(echo "$value_1") <(echo "$value_2")
```

`<(...)` is called *process substitution*.  It makes the output from the command inside the parens look like a file.

#### Improvement

If we don't know the first character in the output, then `printf` is more reliable than `echo`:

```
paste <(printf "%s" "$value_1") <(printf "%s" "$value_2")
```

#### Example

Let's use these two test files:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
$ cat file2
a
b
```

Now, let's read those files into variables and apply paste to those variables:

```
$ value_1=$(cat file1); value_2=$(cat file2)
$ paste <(printf "%s" "$value_1") <(printf "%s" "$value_2")
1       a
2       b
```

Or, saving the output in a variable:

```
$ value_3=$(paste <(printf "%s" "$value_1") <(printf "%s" "$value_2"))
$ echo "$value_3"
1       a
2       b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
value_1=$(cat file_1.txt
value_2=$(cat file_2.txt)
value_3=$(echo $value_1 $value_2 | paste) # or value_3="$value1 $value2"
echo "$value_3"
```

#### Note :

- no space allowed around `=` in shell
- The backquote

  ```
  `
  ```

  is used in the old-style command

substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But it throws me an error saying "paste: line11296: No such file or directory" where line11296 is first row and first column in file_1.txt. kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

The third line should read

```
value_3=`paste file_1.txt file_2.txt`
```

You need the backticks, no space after `value_3` and don't use the variables as arguments, use the file names.

The reason it is saying "file not found" is because the `value_3` with a space after it is being interpreted as a command to be run.